# How to cancel an execution of Write node in Nuke?

Tags: python, multithreading, nuke

I have been writing a Nuke render manager in Python and came across a problem:
`nuke.cancel()` doesn't seem to work right.
My python script creates a main class and connects to a server (written in Java) and then enters an infinite loop, each time getting a new task (in the form of a JSON object). Each loop it gets opens a script? finds the write nodes and executes them. To report progress back to the server I have added callbacks:
`nuke.addBeforeFrameRender(lambda: self._pre_frame_render())`
and
`nuke.addAfterFrameRender(lambda: self._post_frame_render())`
where

```
def _pre_frame_render(self):
    self._host_socket.send(struct.pack('>b', 1))
    self._host_socket.send(struct.pack('>i', nuke.frame()))

def _post_frame_render(self):
    self._host_socket.send(struct.pack('>b', 2))
    self._host_socket.send(struct.pack('>i', nuke.frame()))
```

To enable a `cancel` method on the server, I have a separate thread that runs while the rendering is active and waits for a 'cancel' request

```
class CancelHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input_socket, cancel_callback):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cancel_set = threading.Event()
        self.run_set = threading.Event()
        self._input_socket = input_socket
        self._cancel_callback = cancel_callback

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.run_set.is_set():
                msg_raw = recv_msg(self._input_socket)
                msg = json.loads(msg_raw)
                if 'mode' in msg and msg['mode'] == 'cancel':
                    print msg_raw
                    self.cancel_set.set()
                    self.run_set.clear()
                    self._cancel_callback()
```

The `cancel_callback` is defined as

```
def _cancel_callback(self):
        nuke.cancel()
        self._is_canceled = True
```

Before the loop starts I start the `CancelHandler` thread and on each iteration the `run_set` action is set, and after - cleared to let the main thread communicate. In between that at different stages I check if `cancel_set` has been set in case a 'cancel' request has arrived.

All of the above seems to work fine except for one thing: `nuke.execute()` does absolutely nothing - the render just continues. I have tried putting it in the `nuke.addBeforeFrameRender` and `nuke.addAfterFrameRender` callbacks but that does nothing. Also I thought it might be executing in the wrong thread so I tried `nuke.executeInMainThread(nuke.cancel)` with no luck.

The [documentation](http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/90/pythonreference/) reads:

> execute(nameOrNode, start, end, incr, views, continueOnError= False)
>   ...
>   If Nuke is run with the GUI up, this will pop up a progress meter. If the user hits the cancel button this command will return 'cancelled' error. 
>   If Nuke is run from the nuke command line (ie nuke was started with the -t switch) execute() prints a text percentage as it progresses.
>   If the user types ^C it will aborting the execute() and return a 'cancelled' error.

so I tried replacing `nuke.cancel()` with `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)`
That actually stopped the render but `execute()` never returned so the script couldn't continue

Since `execute()` should

> return a 'cancelled' error

I tried to catch the `nuke.CancelledError` exception both from the `execute()` and the `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` code but it wasn't thrown.

Curiously, when I ran this callback:

```
def _cancel_callback(self):
        self._is_canceled = True
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
        print "Cancelled"
```

the `print` line got executed

I am fairly new to python so it might be a noob's mistake but does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or if it's a bug in the API?
Or maybe someone cam come up with a better solution to the problem - that would be greatly appreciated!

So far the only way out of this situation I see is to simply shut down the worker process and then launch a new one, but that would be kind of an ugly thing to do each time someone wants to cancel a job.

Using Nuke 9.0v3
Full source code can be found at https://bitbucket.org/andrey_glebov/nukerendermanager/src in PYTHON directory

Comment: Great question, and I wish I knew the answer to it. Not an answer, but you might consider using a render queuing system like [Rush](http://seriss.com/rush/), which works with most any software. The way it (and others like it) works is through a clean command line render each time. Nuke command line renderer launches in just a few seconds, so it's probably not worth the effort to try and keep it active between renders.

Comment: Yes, for rendering, the penalty is not to big, but my tasks include batch creating of scripts with specified nodes (mostly for transcoding with processing like high quality up-res or noise reduction), and those can take under a second. If I can't find a viable solution I will only terminate the process when I need to cancel a render.

Comment: I would suggest writing to The Foundry. It does sound like a bug, and they're usually pretty responsive about those. If you find a solution feel free to "answer your own question" here to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The following command cancels a `Progress` window, so it stops a rendering process as well.

```
nuke.toNode('Write1')['disable'].setValue(1)
```